# How to retrieve the full branch path leading to each leaf node of a sklearn Decision Tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have this decision tree, which I would like to extract every branch from it. The image is a portion of the tree, since the original tree is much bigger but it doesn't fit well on a single image.

[image]

I'm not trying to print the rules of the tree like

```
Rules used to predict sample 1400:

decision node 0 : (X[1400, 4] = 92.85714285714286) > 96.42856979370117)
decision node 4 : (X[1400, 3] = 45.03259584336583) > 53.49640464782715)
```

or like:

```
The binary tree structure has 7 nodes and has the following tree structure:

node=0 is a split node: go to node 1 if 4 <= 96.42856979370117 else to node 4.
    node=1 is a split node: go to node 2 if 3 <= 96.42856979370117 else to node 3.
    node=4 is a split node: go to node 5 if 5 <= 0.28278614580631256 else to node 6.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
branch 0: x[4] <= 96.429,x[3]<=96.429,class=B,gini_score=0.5
branch 1: x[4] <= 96.429,x[3]>96.429,class=B,gini_score=0.021
branch 2: x[4] > 96.429,x[5]<=0.283,class=A,gini_score=0.092
branch 4: x[4] > 96.429,x[5]>0.283,class=A,gini_score=0.01
```

Basically, I'm trying to obtain every branch from the top to the leaf node (the full path) with the class and the gini score. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the irist dataset example from sklearn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py) we follow the next steps.

#### 1.Generate an example Decision Tree

Code taken from [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#train-tree-classifier)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree
import numpy as np

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=6, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

#### 2. Retrieve branches paths

First we retrieve the following values from the tree

```
n_nodes = clf.tree_.node_count
children_left = clf.tree_.children_left
children_right = clf.tree_.children_right
feature = clf.tree_.feature
threshold = clf.tree_.threshold
impurity = clf.tree_.impurity
value = clf.tree_.value
```

Inside `retrieve_branches` we calculate the leaf nodes and iterate from the origin node down to the leaf nodes, when we get to a leaf node we return the branch path with a `yield` statement.

```
def retrieve_branches(number_nodes, children_left_list, children_right_list):
    """Retrieve decision tree branches"""
    
    # Calculate if a node is a leaf
    is_leaves_list = [(False if cl != cr else True) for cl, cr in zip(children_left_list, children_right_list)]
    
    # Store the branches paths
    paths = []
    
    for i in range(number_nodes):
        if is_leaves_list[i]:
            # Search leaf node in previous paths
            end_node = [path[-1] for path in paths]

            # If it is a leave node yield the path
            if i in end_node:
                output = paths.pop(np.argwhere(i == np.array(end_node))[0][0])
                yield output

        else:
            
            # Origin and end nodes
            origin, end_l, end_r = i, children_left_list[i], children_right_list[i]

            # Iterate over previous paths to add nodes
            for index, path in enumerate(paths):
                if origin == path[-1]:
                    paths[index] = path + [end_l]
                    paths.append(path + [end_r])

            # Initialize path in first iteration
            if i == 0:
                paths.append([i, children_left[i]])
                paths.append([i, children_right[i]])
```

To call the `retrieve_branches` just pass `n_nodes`, `children_left` and `children_right` and an empty list that will be storing and updating the branches paths. Final display is shown below.

```
all_branches = list(retrieve_branches(n_nodes, children_left, children_right))
all_branches
>>> 
[[0, 1],
 [0, 2, 3, 5],
 [0, 2, 3, 6, 7],
 [0, 2, 3, 6, 8],
 [0, 2, 4, 9],
 [0, 2, 4, 10]]
```

#### 3. Path, value and Gini by Branch

The rules can be obtain from the `feature` and `threshold` values of the `clf.tree_`, as well as the impurity `clf.tree_.impurity` and the values `clf.tree_.value` at the leaf node.

```
for index, branch in enumerate(all_branches):
    leaf_index = branch[-1]
    print(f'Branch: {index}, Path: {branch}')
    print(f'Gin {impurity[leaf_index]} at leaf node {branch[-1]}')
    print(f'Value: {value[leaf_index]}')
    print(f"Decision Rules: {[f'if X[:, {feature[elem]}] <= {threshold[elem]}' for elem in branch]}")
    print(f"---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
>>>
Branch: 0, Path: [0, 1]
Gin 0.0 at leaf node 1
Value: [[37.  0.  0.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Branch: 1, Path: [0, 2, 3, 5]
Gin 0.0 at leaf node 5
Value: [[ 0. 32.  0.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716', 'if X[:, 3] <= 1.6500000357627869', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Branch: 2, Path: [0, 2, 3, 6, 7]
Gin 0.0 at leaf node 7
Value: [[0. 0. 3.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716', 'if X[:, 3] <= 1.6500000357627869', 'if X[:, 1] <= 3.100000023841858', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Branch: 3, Path: [0, 2, 3, 6, 8]
Gin 0.0 at leaf node 8
Value: [[0. 1. 0.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716', 'if X[:, 3] <= 1.6500000357627869', 'if X[:, 1] <= 3.100000023841858', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Branch: 4, Path: [0, 2, 4, 9]
Gin 0.375 at leaf node 9
Value: [[0. 1. 3.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716', 'if X[:, 2] <= 5.049999952316284', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Branch: 5, Path: [0, 2, 4, 10]
Gin 0.0 at leaf node 10
Value: [[ 0.  0. 35.]]
Decision Rules: ['if X[:, 3] <= 0.800000011920929', 'if X[:, 2] <= 4.950000047683716', 'if X[:, 2] <= 5.049999952316284', 'if X[:, -2] <= -2.0']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Miguel. It gives me `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when running `retrieve_branches`. Also noticed that the argument order is not the same order defined in the function and you added an `is_leaves` parameter, which I don't know where it comes from. And the varieble `path` that is inside the function, corresponds to the argument `path_list`?

Comment: Also noticed, when getting the rules of all branches (in step 3) the inequality is always '<='. How that can be fixed?

Comment: @xerac apologies, there were some errors on the function, please check the edit , The sign of the inequality can be changed noticed depending on the threshold.